# is it possible to loop asterisk diamond with 2 small pyramid below it?

Tags: javascript

[image: Diamond with 1 pyramid] [image]

i want to create 2 of these pyramid evenly i have tried adding another else if but it just override it instead

```js
var str5 = "";
for (let i=1; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j=1; j < 10; j++) {
     if (i<= 5 && j >= (5) - (i - 1) && j <= (5) + (i - 1)){
       str5 = str5.concat("*")}else if ( i > 5 && j <= (5 - (5 - i)*(-1)) && j >= (i - 4)){
         str5 = str5.concat("*")
     } else {
       str5 = str5.concat(" ")
     }
  }
  str5 = str5.concat("\n")
}
console.log(str5);
```

Comment: What is the exact output you actually want to see here?

Comment: I have added another image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more generic way to do it:

- With a base of 5, first row will have all stars; second row: blanks replace stars in first and last spots; third row: blanks replace stars in first, second, second last and last spots
- So, for any odd base, each row progressively has blanks replace stars from outside in until there is a single star
- To duplicate horizontally, just repeat the process n times per row

In this snippet, the `symbolPos` array keeps track of which 'spots' you want the symbol and blank otherwise. `symbolPos` has its leading and trailing element removed for each `row` iteration.

```js
function invertedPyramidString(base, repeats, symbol) {
  let str = "";
  if (base % 2 ===0) return "base argument must be odd";
  let rows = (base + 1) / 2; // rows should be half of (base + 1)
  
  let symbolPos = [...Array(base).keys()]; // [0, 1, 2... base-1]
  for (let row=0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let rep=0; rep < repeats; rep++) {
      for (let col=0; col<base; col++) {
        str = str.concat(symbolPos.indexOf(col) > -1 ? symbol : " ");
      }
    }
    symbolPos.shift(); // remove 1st index
    symbolPos.pop(); // remove last symbol
    str = str.concat("\n");
  }
  
  return str;
}

console.log("Base 5; repeats 2; symbol *");
console.log(invertedPyramidString(5, 2, "*"));
console.log("");

console.log("Base 5; repeats 4; symbol *");
console.log(invertedPyramidString(5, 4, "*"));
console.log("");

console.log("Base 7; repeats 3; symbol ^");
console.log(invertedPyramidString(7, 3, "^"));
console.log("");

console.log("Base 13; repeats 4; symbol !");
console.log(invertedPyramidString(13, 4, "!"));
console.log("");

console.log("Base 4; repeats 2; symbol *");
console.log(invertedPyramidString(4, 2, "*"));
console.log("");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```